# Recursively copying all leaves from BST to another BST

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I've worked out the algorithm on how to copy the leaves from a BST to another BST.

1. Check if the tree is empty
2. If we reach a leaf, copy the data to the destination BST.
3. Call the recursive function with source BST -> left and source BST -> right with destination's pointer to the respective direction
4. Otherwise, recursively call without the dest -> left or dest -> right (since we would be going into null).

Would this algorithm work?

```
434 int copy_leaves(node * source, node * & dest)
435 {   
436     if (!source)
437     {
438         dest = NULL;
439         return 0;
440     }
441     
442     if (!(source -> left) && !(source -> right))
443     {
444         dest = new node;
445         dest -> data = source -> data; 
XXX         dest -> left = dest -> right = NULL;
446     }
447     
448     return copy_leaves(source -> left, dest) + //???
449         copy_leaves(source -> right, dest) + 1; //???
450 }
```

Ok I tried implementing my algorithm and there are several faults. I do not quite know where to do the recursive call. I know that I am reaching null after two invocations (then we know the node is a leaf) which means that I copy the data. I don't understand where to pass dest->right and dest -> left for the recursive calls.

Comment: It should work, beware them dirty details. It misses the opportunity to construct a perfectly balanced BST.

Comment: Try it :) Then ask https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ what they think of it :)

Comment: (@FilipHaglund I'm confident you suggest StevenTea to present it on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - almost.) Just noticed that the question _does not_ read _all nodes_.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, the finished implementation :) It's sometimes helpful to run some inputs by hand to see if the algorithm seems to work as expected.

Comment: "there are several faults" is not a problem specification.  You've given us no driver program to reproduce the error.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Your stated purpose for the routine is to copy leaf values, but it returns a value.  What is the purpose of that?  It appears to be counting nodes, but that's not part of your spec for the method.

Comment: (The source code in revision 2 looked _quite_ different from what I assumed to be on your mind given the description in revision 1.) Please state a) what the procedure is to accomplish (shall the copy contain data from just the leaves, or from _every_ node?) and b) what _you_ are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please don't radically alter your post after receiving answers. It makes the answers nonsensical and wastes the time of people trying to help you. Also, you need code (a [mcve]) for this kind of question, but you should remove the line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this works, as written.  I'll echo this with some indentation:

```
BST_copy(src, dst)
    # step 1
    if tree is empty
        <action not specified; assume return>
    else
        # step 2
        if src is a leaf
            copy data to the destination tree
            # step 3
            BST_copy(src->left,  dst->left)
            BST_copy(src->right, dst->right)
        #step 4
        else
            BST_copy(src->left,  dst)
            BST_copy(src->right, dst)
```

- Step 1: you haven't specified the action; please fill in.
- Step 2: Does the destination tree already have a full structure identical to that of the source tree?  If not, how are you managing the copy?
- Step 3: If the tree is a leaf, then there are no left & right subtrees; why are you recurring when you know the links are **null**?
- Step 4: This gets your structures out of synch; you've gone down one level in the source tree, along two branches, but you haven't descended in the destination tree.  If this works in your set-up, then there's something about the tree structure or copy operation that is not yet in this algorithm.

Comment: You didn't have to be so critical. When I stated "I don't understand where to pass dest->right and dest -> left for the recursive calls," what is there not understand in terms of my goal? My goal is simply figure out the correct calls for copying all of the leaves. I figured it out.

Comment: Most of this is follow-up questions for OP. Please make sure you're answering the question. Use comments, not answers, to ask for clarification.